# Design for generic options to algorithms

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to know if there is a design pattern for specifying options to a set of algorithms. I am using C++.
Let me describe my problem. I am having a set of algorithms and these algorithms have different options. I want to design a single point access to these algorithms. Something similar to a strategy pattern. This single point access is a controller class which takes input as a generic options class. Depending upon the options, a suitable algorithm will be used. I want to generalize these options so that i can extend algorithms and the client.
Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [Konrad's suggestion of using policy types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602108/design-for-generic-options-to-algorithms/602119#602119), if your algorithms require parameters at construction time, you can handle this cleanly by requiring that any `Policy` class has a nested type called `Params`, and then provide a constructor inside `fancy_algorithm<Policy>` that takes an argument of this type and passes it to the contained `Policy` object:

```
template <typename Policy>
class fancy_algorithm : private Policy {
public:
    typedef typename Policy::Params Params;    // Need to redeclare :(

    explicit fancy_algorithm(Params params = Params()) : Policy(params) {}
};
```

Any relevant parameters need to be packaged into a single object of type `Policy::Params`.

The `Policy` class is always constructed with a single argument of type `Policy::Params`.  To work with policy classes that (may) require no parameters, provide a default constructor (or use the implicitly declared one) in `Params`, not in `Policy`.  This way, by using a default value for the `fancy_algorithm<Policy>` constructor as above, we enable convenient default-construction of a `fancy_algorithm<Policy>` whenever `Policy::Params` has a default constructor (i.e. when the `Policy` doesn't require any parameters).  No safety is lost: if `Policy::Params` lacks a default constructor (indicating that some parameters are *required*), any attempt to default-construct a `fancy_algorithm<Policy>` object will fail at compile time.

Example:

```
struct multiply_by_params {
    multiply_by_params(int x /* = 42 */) : _x(x) {}     // See bottom
    int get() const { return _x; }    // Or, just make multiply_by a friend

private:
    int _x;
};

struct multiply_by {
    typedef multiply_by_params Params;
    multiply_by(Params p) : _x(p.get()) { /* Other initialisation */ }

    // Other code implementing the strategy (e.g. an operator()())
    ...

private:
    int _x;
};

fancy_algorithm<multiply_by> a(69); // Always compiles
fancy_algorithm<multiply_by> b;     // Compiles iff /* = 42 */ is uncommented
```

Comment: This has got me thinking about policy classes more seriously. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

An often-used pattern is to create a policy class which is passed as a template type to your class and then inherited from privately:

```
template <typename Policy>
class fancy_algorithm : private Policy {
};
```

One famous example of this is the `std::allocator` class which is often inherited in that manner:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class my_container : private Alloc {
public:
    typedef Alloc allocator;

    // It's necessary to make the base class names available explicitly.
    typedef typename allocator::pointer pointer;

    using allocator::construct;
    // …
};
```

Comment: Interesting! At first I thought: Why derive from it? It's not an is-a relationship. But on second thought it makes sense: We inherit all the getters/setters for the options, which is very convenient, so we can set them from the outside.

Comment: @dehmann: Yes, it's counter-intuitive. However, private inheritance doens't model “is-a” relationships, but rather “is-implemented-in-terms-of”. Private inheritance in itself is a highly confusing concept because it is not related to public inheritance *at all*. Basically, private inheritance is …

Comment: (cont’d): … just a convenience notation for private membership in a class (composition). Don’t use it, except in strange cases like the above. This is a special case because it has become an idiom of the language and many C++ library authors immediately know what it means in this context.

Comment: Also, if your algorithms require parameters at construction time, you can handle this by requiring that any Policy class has a nested type called Params, and then provide a constructor inside fancy_algorithm that takes an argument of this type and passes it to the contained Policy object.

Comment: j_random_hacker: excellent remark, completely forgot about those. How about making an own answer out of this technique? A comment isn't really a good place for it. You'll get my up-vote. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I've added a solution with an example.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Konrad on policy-based design. I also recommend [Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315). After this book your vision of C++ will be changed forever ;)